# Отправка письма html со встроенными картинками через smtp?

Tags: php, html, email, smtp

Возникла такая задача - мне нужно отправить письмо со встроенной в его тело картинкой - естественно прибегнув к верстке письма через html.

У меня был подобный опыт, но в прошлый раз я использовал функцию php `mail()`, то есть не прибегал к smtp а сейчас стоит задача - отправить нужно сверстанное в HTML письмо, но через smtp-авторизацию!

делаю так но в письме приходит код ХТМЛ - страница не интерпритируется(

```
  $smtp_server = "mail.******.kz.";
    $port = 25;
    $mydomain = "mail.******.kz.";
    $username = "robot@******.kz";
    $password = "*******";
    $sender = "robot@******.kz";
    $recipient = 'leaderquest@mail.ru';
    $subject = "Регистрация нового пользователя";
    $message = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">
       <html>
         <head><title>Почтовая рассылка</title></head>
         <body><img src='http://www.******.kz/img/logo.jpg' border='0'>Тело сообщения<br><br><img src='http://www.******.kz/img/logo2.jpg' border='0'></body>
       </html>";
    $message = convert_cyr_string($message, "w", "k"); 
    // Initiate connection with the SMTP server
    $handle = fsockopen($smtp_server, $port);
    fputs($handle, "EHLO $mydomain\r\n");

    // SMTP authorization
    fputs($handle, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
    fputs($handle, base64_encode($username)."\r\n");
    fputs($handle, base64_encode($password)."\r\n");

    // Send out the e-mail
    fputs($handle, "MAIL FROM:<$sender>\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "RCPT TO:<$recipient>\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "DATA\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "To: $recipient\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "Subject: $subject\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "$message\r\n");
    fputs($handle, ".\r\n");

    // Close connection to SMTP server
    fputs($handle, "QUIT\r\n");
```

Comment: Почти уверен, что за вас этот скрипт никто не напишет. Предлагаю вам либо начать писать и задавать вопросы по мере их появления, либо использовать библиотеку — и тоже задавать вопросы по мере появления.

Comment: вы правы вот сам теперь и сижу ковыряюсь - но пока только так получается( и не работает

Comment: ну вот с кодом уже лучше. Плюсанул.

Comment: вот если без SMTP просто через sendmail - то то же самое работает без нареканий! если же смтп авторизуюсь то он просто присылает код в письме((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

НУ все блин епть наконец то настроил! Юзайте кому нужно будет!
Работает оно так!

```
 $smtp_server = "mail.mysite.kz.";//название сервера смтп
    $port = 25;//порт чаще всего 25й
    $mydomain = "mail.mysite.kz.";//это вроде вобще не на че не влияет но я пишу сюда адрес хоста
    $username = "robot@mysite.kz";//ящик с которого будем слать письмо
    $password = "1232434234";//пароль от этого ящика
    $sender = "robot@mysite.kz";//как будет подписан отправитель
    $recipient = 'leaderquest@mail.ru';//кому шлем письмо
    $subject = "Регистрация нового пользователя";//заголовок письма
    $message = "
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">

       <html>
         <head><title>Почтовая рассылка</title></head>
         <body>
         <img src='http://cs629516.vk.me/v629516895/121c2/RFEawgP9pbQ.jpg' border='0'></body>
       </html>";


    $handle = fsockopen($smtp_server, $port);
    fputs($handle, "EHLO $mydomain\r\n");


    fputs($handle, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
    fputs($handle, base64_encode($username)."\r\n");
    fputs($handle, base64_encode($password)."\r\n");


    fputs($handle, "MAIL FROM:<$sender>\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "RCPT TO:<$recipient>\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "DATA\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "To: $recipient\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "Subject: $subject\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251\r\n");//у меня на сайте стоит ЮТФ -8 но если ставить ее и тут то в письме будут крокозябры (проверил на мэйл ру) так что ставлю Виндовскую
    fputs($handle, "$message\r\n");
    fputs($handle, ".\r\n");


    fputs($handle, "QUIT\r\n");
```

у меня все заработало наконец! если что то не работает проверяем авторизационные данные!